# CentOS 7.8: Device ens32 does not seem to be present, delaying initialisation

Tags: centos, network-interface

I upgraded my CentOS 7.5 setup to CentOS 7.8 and since then, one of my two NIC's is not starting (VMWare ESXi interfaces). I have to bring it up manually using **ifup ens32** later from VM console (because SSH is not working because the interface is not up).

This is what I find in messages log:

```
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal kernel: e1000 0000:02:00.0 eth0: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:0c:29:87:20:06
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal kernel: e1000 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
... about 100 lines
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal network: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal kernel: e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth1: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:0c:29:87:20:10
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal kernel: e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal network: Bringing up interface ens32:  ERROR     : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device ens32 does not seem to be present, delaying initialisation.
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth: Device ens32 does not seem to be present, delaying initialisation.
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal network: [FAILED]
Aug 12 14:39:15 portal kernel: e1000: ens33 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Aug 12 14:39:20 portal network: Bringing up interface ens33:  [  OK  ]
```

As you can see, ens32 is not initialized while the second NIC ens33 was started successfully. I have no idea about the reason. Any idea how I can fix this? There were no issues like that before the upgrade...

I neither renamed the devices nor did I change the MAC or anything else. Just updating CentOS.

Comment: Can't tell why the NIC is not presented at boot. I'd suggest removing it and adding a `VMXNET 3` NIC instead of `E1000`. It's faster, less burden on host CPU, supported by your VM OS and suggested by VMware.

Comment: @Krackout Thanks. I'm in preparation of an appliance update and I can not tell all my customers to reconfigure their VMs before updating. As it worked with previous CentOS 7.5, I think it is an issue of CentOS 7.8? Maybe I can handle this without changing the VMs settings?

Comment: You could add this string to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, e.g. `sleep 60; ifup ens32`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, but I also do have mount-points (for SMB share) and other services that need the interface to be up. So the initial mount fails and I would have to also (re)start these services, too. I do not really like this idea. Sounds like a workaround without solving the issue.

Looks like the network service is running before udev has had time to rename the interfaces? Can I add delay or chenge the order?

Comment: VMWare ESXi costs money - open a support ticket and request an issue to be solved.